# cannot use multiple select queries in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

Is it that pgadmin 4 does not support the execution of multiple select queries?

I tried executing this query

```
select cust, prod 
from sales;

select * 
from sales
```

it only showed me one table

Comment: If you found my answer helpful then could you accept it using checkmark?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing semicolon after first query which is **incorrect SQL syntax**.

```
select cust, prod 
from sales;

select * 
from sales;
```

FYI, do not expect two separate results after executing it in query tool, you will only get result from last query only.

**Updates for WITH clause question.**

```
with Min_cust as (
        select cust, max(quant),min(quant) from sales group by cust
    ),
    FinalMin as (
        select sales.cust,sales.prod,minium from sales 
        natural join Min_cust as A where sales.quant=A.min
    ) 
    select * from FinalMin;
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem.
I am also getting an error when i use 2 with queries consecutively.

with Min_cust as
  (select cust, max(quant),min(quant)
 from sales 
 group by cust);
  
with FinalMin as     
    (select sales.cust,sales.prod,minium 
    from sales natural join Min_cust as A
    where sales.quant=A.min)
    select * 
    from FinalMin;
can you please help me with this @n33rma